# How to make Istanbul generate coverage for all of my source code?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai, istanbul

Currently Istanbul is only generating coverage for files that are used in my tests, which is okay, but seems to defeat the purpose of having coverage somewhat.

I have no Istanbul configuration, and am invoking it via `npm test` with the following script string:

`$ istanbul cover _mocha -- -R dot --check-leaks --recursive test/`

Is there a way to generate coverage for all of my source code?

Comment: Maybe this thread will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702578/full-gulp-istanbul-coverage-report/26418759#26418759 (but this requires using gulp). Using includeUntested option without gulp might also help (https://github.com/SBoudrias/gulp-istanbul#includeuntested).

Comment: This looks promising, thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found the answer, I think I'm partly lucky that the directory structure I have chosen allows me to use this option, but my test command is now:

`$ istanbul --include-all-sources cover _mocha -- -R dot --recursive test/`

The `--include-all-sources` is the important part.

Comment: This makes me think it's possible, but the --include-all-sources is for mocha, correct? What was your directory structure? I'm still trying to get this to work.. :(

Comment: Does --include-all-sources count up all .js files in your project, not just the ones hit by the runtime?

Comment: This works for me, but covers my entire working directory. Does anyone know how I would get coverage for only my `src` folder?

Comment: Just figured that out. You need to combine `--include-all-sources` with `--root`. For my code it was simply `--include-all-sources --root ./src`. I found this command here: https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/112#issuecomment-281078341

Answer (score 8):

Istanbul recommends using [nyc](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc) in order to check code coverage. It suggests an approach like this:

```
nyc mocha
```

After running this command, we'll get the coverage report. But there is a couple of pitfalls.

First of all, by default `mocha` is looking for tests in folder `test`. In order to override it, we have to set our own path in file `mocha.opts` like this:

```
nyc mocha --opts ./mocha.opts
```

And `mocha.opts` contains such code, for example:

```
spec/unit/back-end/**/*.spec.js
```

Another problem is that by default `nyc` checks coverage of only required files, that is your question is about. The solution is to set two options for `nyc` (I run test as an npm script so I set options in package.json). Here is the code:

```
"nyc": {
  "all": true,
  "include": [
    "routes/*.js",
    "routes/**/*.js",
    "models/*.js"
  ]
},
"scripts": {
  "mocha": "nyc mocha --opts ./mocha.opts",
}
```

Another way to achieve it is to set not `include`, but `exclude` option in order to exclude from coverage checking inappropriate files. It's strange, but the sole option `all` doesn't work, it requires `include` or `exclude` options. You can get more info about `nyc` options via `nyc --help`.

P.S. I don't know `nyc` and  `mocha` deeply and I'm only based on my own experience.

Answer (score 1):

For generating coverage for all files, have the following in your package.json

> "istanbulCoverage": "**nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=text-lcov --all -x
>   \"./node_modules/*\" -x \"./coverage/*\" check-coverage --functions 90 npm run test**"

Here **--all** flag fetches all the files in your project. If u want to exclude specific files or folders, you can use **-x** option.

Apart from this, if you want to specify coverage rate for you application, then use **check-coverage** option to specify the threshold. In my case, I've specified functions to have a coverage threshold of 90%. Otherwise, the coverage report generation fails.(i am running my karma test after coverage report generation).

Hope this helped:)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `--include-all-sources` did not work for me. Files that were not `require`-d were still excluded from the final coverage report.

Eventually, I came across [this issue](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/112) on the `istanbul` GitHub where the maintainer stated:

> Yes, that is expected behavior. istanbul works by hooking require so if a file is never require-d it is as if it doesn't exist.

The only fool-proof solution that I found was to manually `require` all files that I wanted to include in my coverage report. I create the file `include-all.test.js` alongside my other test scripts and added the following bit of code:

```
var glob = require( 'glob' )
var path = require( 'path' );

glob.sync( './path/to/js/code/*.js' ).forEach( function( file ) {
    // we don't care about errors here, we just want to require the file
    try {
        require( path.resolve( file ) );
    } catch(e) {}
});
```

This will absolutely ensure that your untested files are included in the `istanbul` coverage report.

Comment: I tried this also. But unfortunately it is also not working. This is my command: `./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover --handle-sigint app.js`

Comment: Same here.  It definitely requires the files, but they don't show up in the report.