# Istanbul Code Coverage

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, istanbul

I have a React project with tests written in Mocha. Istanbul is used to get the test coverage.

I have 4 react components in a folder called `lib` and in the `test` folder, I have only tests written for 2 of the components. When Istanbul reports the coverage, it says 100% but clearly it's not 100% for the project because there are components without tests. How to get the correct coverage report for the components in `lib` folder?

My `.istanbul.yml` looks like this

```
instrumentation:
  root: ./lib
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
reporting:
    print: summary
    reports:
        - lcov
    dir: ./coverag
```

And the script in `package.json` looks like this

```
"code_cov": "babel-node ./node_modules/istanbul/lib/cli.js cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- ./test/**/*.spec.js"
```

and the folder structure looks like this

```
/
  /lib
   - Component1.jsx
   - Component2.jsx
   - Component3.jsx
   - Component4.jsx
  /test
   - Component1.spec.js
   - Component2.spec.js
   - Component3.spec.js
   - Component4.spec.js
.istanbul.yml
package.json
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Any guidance would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606071/how-to-make-istanbul-generate-coverage-for-all-of-my-source-code).

The solution is using `include-all-sources` flag added [here](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/pull/275).

In your case it should be:

```
"code_cov": "babel-node ./node_modules/istanbul/lib/cli.js --include-all-sources cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- ./test/**/*.spec.js"
```